# React Native, add two return statements to useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I add two return statements to my `useEffect` hook? I would like to add an event listener to my current hook.

Event listener:

```
const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
  if (
    appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
    nextAppState === "active"
  ) {
    console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
  }

  appState.current = nextAppState;
  setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
  console.log("AppState", appState.current);
});

return () => {
  subscription.remove();
};
```

Current hook:

```
useEffect(() => {

    async function checkRefresh() {
        if (
            daysDiffToNow(lastUpdatedTimestamp) > 0 &&
            appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
            nextAppState === "active"
        ) {
            await onRefreshAppData();
        }
    }
    checkRefresh();

    const updateLastUpdatedTextCallback = (value) => {
        setState((prevState) => ({
            ...
        }));
    };
    const id = setInterval(() => {
        updateLastUpdatedTextCallback(lastUpdatedTimestamp);
    }, TIME_INTERVAL_IN_MILISECONDS);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
}, [lastUpdatedTimestamp]);

const close = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
        ...
    }));
};
```

Comment: You can add multiple functions inside one return statement. Like this:-return () => {clearInterval(id);
  subscription.remove();
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply put them top to bottom inside the `useEffect` and have a `return` function that would look like this (it executes at once the code for the two return statements needed):

```js
return () => {
  subscription.remove(); // the first
  clearInterval(id); // the second
};
```